# Able to see a preview of hidden elements before page load in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

So on my webpage, I have several elements that should be hidden on initial page load (like error messages) but should be shown if they satisfy certain conditions. I'm using Angular JS.

The problem is that although it works perfectly in Chrome, in Firefox, you can briefly see a preview of the hidden elements which then disappear after the page has fully loaded. I want to avoid this.

```
<span id="invalidDate" ng-show="invalidDateEntered==true" class="alert">Invalid Date Format</span>
```

So I can see this alert `Invalid Date Format` before the page has loaded fully in Firefox but it disappears soon after. I've tried using `ng-init` to prevent this, but it hasn't helped.

```
<span id="invalidDate" ng-init="invalidDateEntered=false" ng-show="invalidDateEntered==true" class="alert">Invalid Date Format</span>
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-cloak on elements:-

```
<span id="invalidDate" ng-cloak ng-show="invalidDateEntered==true" class="alert">Invalid Date Format</span>
```

In Css:-

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I also found this https://blog.svpino.com/2014/10/09/angularjs-developers-beware-of-ngcloak to be helpful.

Comment: Yes i read this post earlier it says basically use ng-cloak on the particular element which you want to render not on the complete body :-)